# ReferenceError: error is not defined, while trying to use function composition

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, ecmascript-6

I have defined two simple functions in nodejs:

```
function findEntityDetailsAsIs(modelname, callback) {
     modelname.find({}, function(error, result) {
         if (error)
           callback (error, null);
         else {
           //console.log(result);
           callback (null, result);
         }
    });
};
```

This is my first function and another function is

```
function printEntitydetails(error, entitydetails, callback) {
   console.log(entitydetails);
}
```

I am trying to call these functions as such

```
findEntityDetailsAsIs(fieldLabel, printEntitydetails(error, entitydetails));
```

But as i try to run this function call it throws an error

```
ReferenceError: error is not defined
```

But error is just as placeholder object i am passing from callback.

```
 findEntityDetailsAsIs(fieldLabel, printEntitydetails(entitydetails));
```

I tried skipping error in the call but this time it gives this error.

```
ReferenceError: entitydetails not  is not defined
```

As per my knowledge the `findEntityDetailsAsIs` should provide the context for the `entitydetails`, as i have provided a `callback(null, result)`.

Comment: When you add parenthesis after function name, it will call it and pass its output as callback. Try `printEntitydetails.bind(null, error, entitydetails)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `findEntityDetailsAsIs` expects to get the callback function, not the execution result of it.
You need to provide only the function name:

```
 findEntityDetailsAsIs(fieldLabel, printEntitydetails);
```

When you run it like you do, you pass to `findEntityDetailsAsIs` the *result* of `printEntitydetails` instead of the function itself. since the function returns nothing, you get undefined

Comment: OP is getting *ReferenceError: error is not defined*. Even I suspected the same issue but error message says otherwise

Comment: The answer should work.
If you are still getting error mean something else is wrong I am not sure but may be versioning issue

Comment: But can you tell me how to structure the callbacks or may be function definition if i have to use the execution result of another function ?

For example 

`function 1(somedata,
                 function2(dataProcessedByfunction1,
                 function3(dataProcessedByfunction2,)));`

And the chain can be upto n functions long. 

My objective is to modularize the functions each function doing exactly one task and then create a chain of the functions to complete the whole process. 
Hope i am clear to you